# Implementar RN-Range-Slider en Storybook para React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

¡Buenas a todos! Estoy creando una story en Storybook y necesito que se muestre en componente RN-Range-Slider. El componente funciona genial en la app, pero a la hora de mostrarlo en el Storybook me da este error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rn-range-slider/index.tsx 32:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

La story esta de está de forma

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';

import SVDRange from "./SVDRange";

// More on default export: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#default-export
export default {
    title: "Filters/SVDRange",
    component: SVDRange,
    // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes
} as ComponentMeta<typeof SVDRange>;

// More on component templates: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#using-args
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof SVDRange> = (args) => <SVDRange {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
// More on args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args
Primary.args = {
    currency: "€",
    Max: 100,
    Min : 0,
    filtertext : [],
    setFiltertext : () => {},
    SetmaxValue: () => {},
    SetminValue: () => {},   
    setShowFilter: () => {},
    setCurrentPage: () => {},
};
```

Alguno se le ocurre qué puede estar pasando. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar está solución, que podría funcionar, que va la línea de lo que comentas Pablo. Añadiendo eso mismo al main.js del storybook.

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web",
    "storybook-addon-apollo-client",
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": "/\.tsx?$/",
        "use": "ts-loader",
        "exclude": "/node_modules/",
      },
    ],
  },
  
}
```